# How to deal with subdomains in a mvc iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
    "{controller}.localhost:5096",                            
    "{action}/{id}",                                        
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
));
```

without iis all good

with iis I have

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

http://develop.localhost:5096/

Comment: You need to set your IIS site to respond to that hostname.

Comment: Is `DomainRoute` the same as the one mentioned in http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to change your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) to route that subdomain to 127.0.0.1. By the way, the hosts file does not accept wildcards, so you will need to list each of your subdomains. This should not be a problem when running outside localhost since you will be able to use wildcards.

[I've done something similar](http://geekstuff.cc/2011/12/02/subdomain-routing-on-asp-net-mvc/), but in my case I've used fixed subdomain names, but I think it may help you.